# Converting string to XML node in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I've an XML string in database column like this

```xml
<trueFalseQuestion id="585" status="correct" maxPoints="10" 
                   maxAttempts="1" 
                   awardedPoints="10" 
                   usedAttempts="1" 
                   xmlns="http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring/quizbuilder/quizresults">
    <direction>You have NO control over how you treat customers.</direction>
    <answers correctAnswerIndex="1" userAnswerIndex="1">
        <answer>True</answer>
        <answer>False</answer>
    </answers>
</trueFalseQuestion>
```

But I need to do XML operations on this string like select its name, attributes values,inner text etc. How can I make this possible from this string

EDIT

Im sharing the code snippet I tried, but not working

```
        Dim myXML As String
        Dim gDt As New DataTable
        gDt.Columns.Add("id")
        gDt.Columns.Add("questionid")
        gDt.Columns.Add("serial")
        gDt.Columns.Add("direction")
        Dim dr As DataRow


            myXML ='<my above shared XML>'
            Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(myXML)
            dr = gDt.NewRow
            dr("serial") = 1
            dr("id") = xmlDoc.Attributes("id").Value
            dr("direction") = xmlDoc("direction").InnerText
             gDt.Rows.Add(dr)
```

But thats not working at all as I wish

Comment: You can start by [loading the string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx) inside a [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @the_lotus Please check my edit

Comment: What do you mean by "but not working" and "thats not working at all as I wish" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to parse XML in .NET, such as using one of the serialization classes or the `XmlReader` class, but the two most popular options would be to parse it with either `XElement` or `XmlDocument`.  For instance:

```
Dim input As String = "<trueFalseQuestion id=""585"" status=""correct"" maxPoints=""10"" maxAttempts=""1"" awardedPoints=""10"" usedAttempts=""1"" xmlns=""http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring/quizbuilder/quizresults""><direction>You have NO control over how you treat customers.</direction><answers correctAnswerIndex=""1"" userAnswerIndex=""1""><answer>True</answer><answer>False</answer></answers></trueFalseQuestion>"
Dim element As XElement = XElement.Parse(input)
Dim id As String = element.@id
```

Or:

```
Dim input As String = "<trueFalseQuestion id=""585"" status=""correct"" maxPoints=""10"" maxAttempts=""1"" awardedPoints=""10"" usedAttempts=""1"" xmlns=""http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring/quizbuilder/quizresults""><direction>You have NO control over how you treat customers.</direction><answers correctAnswerIndex=""1"" userAnswerIndex=""1""><answer>True</answer><answer>False</answer></answers></trueFalseQuestion>"
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(input)
Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("q", "http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring/quizbuilder/quizresults")
Dim id As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("/q:trueFalseQuestion/@id", nsmgr).InnerText
```

Based on your updated question, it looks like the trouble you were having is that you weren't properly specifying the namespace.  If you use `XElement`, it's much more forgiving (i.e. loose), but when you use XPath to select nodes in an `XmlDocument`, you need to specify every namespace, even when it's the default namespace on the top-level element of the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that information.. But just one more question if you dont mind, How can I select that node without knowing the "/q:trueFalseQuestion/@id" part.. I mean I just need to select the whole node under the string . Also its not trueFalseQuestion always..

Comment: The `DocumentElement` property of the `XmlDocument` object returns the top-level element in the document.  Other than that, you could loop through the list of elements via the `ChildNodes` property.